# Mpdf bulk data loading issue

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, mpdf

I am using mpdf for pdf export. Its working fine for me. But while trying to load bulk data with mpdf it showing memory exhausted error. I have tried to print all data before writing to mpdf. It showing all data correctly. but while trying to load these data in mpdf it showing above error. Anybody can support me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Add this line
OR
Increase memory limit in php.ini file

```
 memory_limit = 256M
```